# WooCommerce - Large number of product variations (200+)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have a variable product with 238 variations (7 sizes and 34 colours).
We are using the [Bulk Variation Forms](https://woocommerce.com/products/bulk-variation-forms/) plugin for the single shop page.

The problem is that with 238 variations, the WooCommerce `->get_available_variations()` method takes an extremely long time (minimum of 5s and as long as 10-20s). This makes the page loading speed unacceptable.

How can I improve the page loading?

Comment: on which page do you use `get_available_variations()` ?

Comment: On the single product page.

Comment: on the `save_post` action, you can cache the result of the method in a metavalue. after that you can change the action `woocommerce_variable_add_to_cart` in order to use this metavalue.